# No CUDA support Error even though WITH_CUDA=ON in CMake

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I have tried to use OpenCV with CUDA supports.

I installed Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64, OpenCV 3.1.0, and CUDA 7.5.

After Cmake Generate with WITH_CUDA = ON, the results for Configure are in the below.

I have referred Markustp's question page [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317625/opencv-wont-build-with-cuda-even-though-with-cuda-on-in-cmake) for my situation,

and [link 2](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/c8ff7a486735f45f9dd4060111b71957c78142c6)  about fixing opencv_world

As commented in the first link,
I've already replaced "-L" by "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH_FLAG}" in CMAKELists.txt (file in C:\opencv\sources\CMakeLists.txt), 
just as Dubrzr's advice.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add CUDA libraries (needed for apps/tools, samples)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(HAVE_CUDA)
  set(OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS ${OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}     ${CUDA_npp_LIBRARY})
  if(HAVE_CUBLAS)
    set(OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS ${OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS} ${CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY})
  endif()
  if(HAVE_CUFFT)
    set(OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS ${OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS} ${CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY})
  endif()
  foreach(p ${CUDA_LIBS_PATH})
  ---original source: set(OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS ${OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS} -L${p}
  ---revised part   : set(OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS ${OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS} ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH_FLAG}${p})
  endforeach()
endif()
```

Next, I generated OpenCV.sln,

Already completed Build and Stall in Debug, Release option(X64) without any errors.

When I built the opencv-cuda code like this,

```
#include <opencv2\cvconfig.h>
#include <opencv2\core\cvdef.h>
#include <opencv2\core\base.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\cuda.hpp>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp>
#include <opencv2\world.hpp>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
int nDevices;
//cv::cuda::setDevice(0);
try{
cout << cv::cuda::getDevice();
}
catch (const cv::Exception& ex){
std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << endl;
}

int a = cv::cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();
//if (cv::cuda::DeviceInfo::isCompatible())
//{
//printf("Device is Compatible with OpenCV GPU-built binaries \n");
//}


printf("Enabled device count: %d\n", a);
cudaGetDeviceCount(&nDevices);

for (int i = 0; i < nDevices; i++){
cudaDeviceProp prop;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, i);
printf("Device Number : %d\n", i);
printf("Device name: %s\n", prop.name);
printf("Memory Clock Rate (KHz): %d\n", prop.memoryClockRate);

}
return 0;
}
```

the result is,

```
OpenCV Error: No CUDA support <The library is compiled without CUDA support> in throw_no_cuda, 
file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2\core\private.cuda.hpp, line 97
Error: C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2\core\private.cuda.hpp, line 97:    
error: <-216> The library is compiled without CUDA support in funtion throw_no_cuda

Enabled device count: 0
Device Number : 0
Device name: GeForce GTX TITAN Z
Memory Clock Rate <kHz>: 3505000
Device Number : 1
Device name: GeForce GTX TITAN Z
Memory Clock Rate <kHz>: 3505000
```

I think that CUDA installed well(CUDA function cudaGetDeviceCount worked well, but there maybe problem in the function throw_no_cuda(OpenCV function??)....

Somebody helps me please T.T.

I spends all the past week days to fix this.

How can I fix this error in 
C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12 shared\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp

I cannot find even the above directory, C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64...

Comment: Thank you! I added 'CMakeLists.txt' part that I modified.

Comment: Try [this](http://users.wpi.edu/~szhou2/opencv3-on-windows.html)

Comment: Solved!! I should have moved 'dll files' such as 'opencv_world310.dll and opencv_ts310.dll' (after Cmake build and intall) to the directory where 'cuda_opencv_test.exe', which is my cuda-opencv collabo test cu file, exists.

Comment: Great! Now you can either answer your own question (if you think it might be useful to others), or delete this question.